# EWS PullSubscription for New or Modified Calendar Events

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

I have been searching for an EWS pullsubscription example that allows me to get a list of calendar events that have been created or modified for a user since the pull subscription has been started.  I have working code to get this info for the Inbox but I haven't found a good example for how to do this for the Calendar.

Below is an example for the Inbox; can anyone provide me with a link or a code example to accomplish the same thing for Calendar events or appointments using an Exchange Web Service pull subscription?

```
    ExchangeService service;
    PullSubscription subscriptionInbox;

    private void SetService() {
        service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);
        service.Url = new Uri("https://mail.myserver.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx");
    }

    private void SetSubscription() {
        if(service == null) {
            SetService();
        }
        // Subscribe to pull notifications in the Inbox folder, and get notified when
        // a new mail is received, when an item or folder is created, or when an item
        // or folder is deleted. 
        subscriptionInbox = service.SubscribeToPullNotifications(
        new FolderId[] { WellKnownFolderName.Inbox },
        5 /* timeOut: the subscription will end if the server is not polled within 5 minutes. */,
        null /* watermark: null to start a new subscription. */,
        EventType.NewMail, EventType.Modified);
    }

    private void btnGetLatestMessages_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if(subscriptionInbox == null) {
            SetSubscription();
        }
        GetEventsResults eventsInbox = subscriptionInbox.GetEvents();
        EmailMessage message;
        // Loop through all item-related events.
        foreach(ItemEvent itemEvent in eventsInbox.ItemEvents) {
            switch(itemEvent.EventType) {
                case EventType.NewMail:
                    try {
                        Item item = Item.Bind(service, itemEvent.ItemId);
                        if(item.ItemClass.ToLower() == "IPM.Note".ToLower()) {
                            message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, itemEvent.ItemId);
                            MessageBox.Show("Inbox/NewMail - " + message.Subject);
                        }
                    } catch(Exception ex) {
                        MessageBox.Show("EventType.NewMail - " + itemEvent.ItemId);
                    }
                    break;
                case EventType.Modified:
                    try {
                        Item item = Item.Bind(service, itemEvent.ItemId);
                        if(item.ItemClass.ToLower() == "IPM.Note".ToLower()) {
                            message = EmailMessage.Bind(service, itemEvent.ItemId);
                            MessageBox.Show("Inbox/Modified - " + message.Subject);
                        }
                    } catch(Exception ex) {
                        MessageBox.Show("EventType.NewMail - " + itemEvent.ItemId);
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question had the answer to my question ;)

Answer (score 6):

Simply subscribe to the calendar instead of your inbox with the event types specified.

```
var subscriptionCalendar = service.SubscribeToPullNotifications(
    new[] { new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar) }, 
    1440, 
    null, 
    EventType.Created, EventType.Modified);
```

Alternatively, you could create one pull notification for `FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox)` and `FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar)` with the `EventType`'s you want.